# javascript cannot return false when confirm cancel

Tags: javascript, confirm

i'm new to js. I have a lil problem,i have 2 functions , one to delete data and one to refresh the page

```
function btndeleteClick(){
    var btn = $get("<%=btndeleteall.ClientID %>");
    btn.click();
    return true;
}      

function RefreshPage() {
    if (confirm('Anda akan menghapus Material yang belum terpakai')==true){
        btndeleteClick();
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the things is when i press cancel on confirmation , it still delete my data, any suggestions ?
thanks :)
pe2s

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: Is this the actual code? What is `$get` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java-script code is looking  correct. I don't confirm but if you add this script on form `onsubmit` event then please check you have add `return before function or not in form tag`.

```
<form name="frmname" id="frmname" method="post" action="" onsubmit = "return RefreshPage()" />
```

If you can add  your form code then it will be better to understand problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've put the code on [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zNDWF/) and the code works correctly. So your problem is somewhere else.